# rsh runs perfectly in normal user but not in root, very strange, why?

Tags: linux, centos, tcp, rsh

When I run command, `rsh localhost pwd` as a root

It shows below output.

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
Trying krb4 rsh...
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
trying normal rsh (/usr/bin/rsh)
rcmd: socket: Permission denied
```

When I run the same command from normal user named `service`. Then it shows below output.

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
Trying krb4 rsh...
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
trying normal rsh (/usr/bin/rsh)
/home/service
```

Why this behavior happening?

Comment: There seems to be a bit of confusion as to the way RCP reports. On some servers I don't have these error messages, however on another new RH server I noticed that the RCP is doing a "krb4" authentication (whatever that means). When this fails it then makes an attempt to copy the file using normal authentication. I noticed that despite all the messages the file does get copied. (not that I like RCP).

Answer (score 3):

The first example tries to login as `root` on the system and run `pwd` while the second example logins via `service` and runs `pwd`.

It is likely that your configuration does either not allow logins as root or from root at localhost.

To debug it further you can try to run `rsh -l service localhost pwd` and see if it works. Please also have a look at [Why can't I use strace with rsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67746/why-cant-i-use-strace-with-rsh/67972#67972) which explains another possible issue.

Comment: When I run `rsh -l service localhost pwd` from root, it shows the same error. , .i.e., `Permission Denied`

Comment: @jhamb then have a look at the `rhosts`/`/etc/hosts.equiv` file of your service user and add an entry for the root user...

Comment: /etc/hosts.equiv only one line i.e., `+ service`. Now I added one more line `+ root`. Then I reboot, but when I run `rsh localhost pwd` from root , but I shows again `Permission Denied`. What can I do now ?

Comment: @jhamb use `rsh -l service localhost` and read the documentation of rsh to understand the issues.

Comment: In root, `rsh -l service localhost pwd` works, but `rsh localhost pwd` not works.

Comment: Can you give answer of above comment?

Answer (score 1):

Erradicate `rsh` immediately. It is a **huge** security risk. No, "this is just an internal network, there won't be any evil chinese hackers" is totally irrelevant, attacks are either automated (to recruit for botnets) or targeted, and the second ones are (depending on the statistics you want to believe) initiated by internal users in 80 to 95% of the cases.

Use `ssh`, it gives almost the same benefits but is much more secure. Yes, it is a bit harder to set up, but not that much.

Comment: Would have upvoted a thousand times if I could.

Answer (score 0):

RSH is very insecure - Do you really want anyone with a packet sniffer to see *any* passwords go over with wire, with the user id, in PLAIN TEXT?

It should have been dropped from the distros as soon as SSH was made readily available, but someone still worried that it might break someone's ancient, highly insecure, script from 1986.

#### RSH is bad juju!

However, I'll let you shoot yourself in the foot - because it's UNIX, and you might really want an excuse when your boss fires you for allowing your servers to be hacked because you don't want to figure out SSH.

One possible reason is that your root account is denied direct login access to the server itself via `rsh`.  Below is a link on how to disable remote shell for root, by only allowing root on `/dev/console`. You are doing the opposite.

http://home.shafe.com/docs/remoteroot.html

There's a similar setting for root with SSH. It's a simple flag in the sshd_config.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-direct-root-login-and-user-access-via-ssh-to-server/

#### Please use SSH instead.